# Bootstrap accordion-toggle loads the content symbol(+/-) wrongly on first time page load

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, visualforce

Hi I have used the below accordion-toggle code on my visualforce page. The collapsible toggle works fine, except while loading the page for the first time. On pageload/Refresh, the collapsed panel appears with the symbol '-' instead of the expected content '+'. Could someone please help me with it?

Visualforce page code:

```
<a hef="#" class="accordion-toggle" data-target="#collapse1" data-toggle="collapse">&nbsp; Data Panel 1 </a>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
       <ul style="list-style-type:none">
             <li> <a hef="#" class="accordion-toggle" data-target="#collapse9" data-toggle="collapse">&nbsp;&nbsp; Data Panel 2</a>
                <div id="collapse9" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                      <ul style="list-style-type:none">
                           <li><font style="color:#337ab7"> Description</font></li>
                       </ul>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li> <a hef="#" class="accordion-toggle" data-target="#collapse8" data-toggle="collapse">&nbsp; &nbsp;Data Panel 3</a>
                <div id="collapse8" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                     <ul style="list-style-type:none">
                           <li><font style="color:#337ab7"> Node 1</font></li>
                           <li><font style="color:#337ab7"> Node 2</font></li>
                           <li><font style="color:#337ab7"> Node 3</font></li>
                      </ul>                                                                                              

                </div>
             </li>
         </ul>
     </div>
```

CSS Style:

```
  .accordion-toggle:after {
                    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';  
                    content: "\e082";   <!-- taken from bootstrap.css -->
                    float: left;          
                }

                 .accordion-toggle.collapsed:after {
                    content: "\e081";   <!-- taken from bootstrap.css -->
                }

                a 
                {cursor: pointer; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set them to `class="accordion-toggle collapsed"` in the markup. This was they will be initally set to a state of collapse and show the `+` icon.

http://codeply.com/go/909KJuqOs5

Comment: That was really helpful. Thank u so much. :-)